# Is the Wikipedia article on the proof for Bertrand's Postulate correct?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primorial

I was checking out the Wikipedia article on the proof of [Bertrand's Postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate#Lemma_4).

For **Lemma 4**, the argument is made for $x\ge 3, x\#<2^{2x-3}$

Here's the proof by induction:

> - $n = 3$: $n\# = 6 < 8$
> - $n = 4$: $n\# =6 < 32$
> - If $n$ odd, $n = (2m-1)\# < 2^{2(2m-1)-3}$
> - If $n$ even, $n = (2m)\# < 2^{2(2m)-3}$
> - $n\# < 2^{2n-3}$
>
> Thus the lemma is proven.

I am assuming that there is a correct way to state this proof.  Proof by induction would mean that we assume that the basis is true up to $n$ and then we show if it is true for $n$, it is true for $n+1$.

The basis is $n=3$ and $n=4$.

The inductive step is stated without proof.  Am I correct?  Or is this point referring to a well known result?

---

Edit:  As I thought about it, it seems to me that the $2n-3$ part is arbitrary.  For example, it is easy to make an argument for $2n-5$.  I wanted to check if my reasoning is correct about this.

Here is the argument for $n \ge 4$:

(1)  $2^{2(4)-5} = 2^{3} = 8 > 4\# = 6$

(2)  Assume it is true up to $n-1$ where $(n-1) > 4$

(3)  if $n$ is even, it is true since $n\# = (n-1)\#$ so we can assume $n$ is odd.

(4)  There exists $m$ such that $n = 2m-1$

(5)  $(1+1)^{2m-2} = \dfrac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2m-1}{{2m-1}\choose{i}} = \sum\limits_{i=0}^{m-1}{{2m-1}\choose{i}} > \dfrac{(2m-1)!}{(m)!(m-1)!} > \dfrac{(2m-1)\#}{m\#}$

(6)  $(m\#)(2)^{2m-2} > (2m-1)\#$

(7)  Since by assumption, $m\# < 2^{2m-5}$, we have:

$$2^{2m-5}\cdot2^{2m-2} = 2^{4m-7} = 2^{2(2m-1)-5} > (2m-1)\# = n\#$$

Is something in my argument wrong?  If not, I suspect that I can go lower than $5$ to any arbitrary number that I wish (so long as I keep increasing $n$.  So, something is probably wrong.  If you can let me know, I would appreciate it.

Comment: It may or may not be correct. Generally the math content is not subjected to the same kinds of shenanigans are articles on other topics, but you're still wise to distrust Wikipedia.

Comment: I agree.  I'm hoping that it is correct.  I'm working on the explanation.  If I find a way to prove it, I'll edit my question and post the reasoning.

Comment: I think $2^{2(2m-3)}$ should be $2^{2(2m)-3}.$ Just a typo in the article.

Comment: I fixed it.  Thanks.

Comment: Here is a link to Erdos' article. http://www.renyi.hu/~p_erdos/1989-29.pdf. The discussion is in the first couple of pages. His proof in form is pretty much that of the Wiki article. In Erdos' proof by assuming $p<n$ he shows $\geq n+1.$ That *is* the induction.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  The Wikipedia article used to be $n\# < 4^n$  It was changed to $n\# < 2^{2m-3}$ but didn't include the argument for it.  My reasoning above is based on my memory of Erdos's argument.

Comment: I don't see how the proof works with $p\#_{p\leq n}<2^{2n-3},$ which is what their definition of $p\#$ implies. By proving $n = 2m-1$ you are only showing that $P(n)\implies P(n).$ Erdos uses $p<n$ and shows this implies $p=n+1.$

Comment: You might be spotting the mistake.  As I understand it, you are showing first that it is true up to $n-1$, then you are showing that if $n-1$, then $n$ with $n=2m-1$. Erdos does it the standard way.  You assume up to $n$ and then show that if up to $n$ is true then $n+1$ is true.  Maybe I am misunderstanding your point.

Comment: There are essentially two kinds of people who mess up Wikipedia articles: those who honestly think they're improving the article, and those who are deliberately trying to put mistakes into it. Changing $4^n$ to $2^{2m - 3}$ strikes me as coming from someone who honestly thought this was better but didn't think it through.

Comment: @RobertSoupe: I was thinking the same thing. It's nice to have a solid reference, which the $4^n$ version was.